# Multiple conditions using df(loc) Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below script.

I am getting stuck on the last line. So if the column recencypct <=0.25 it's going to be in the first quartile, when it's above 0.75, it's in the 4th quartile.

I am trying to add multiple conditions to calculate the second and third quartile.

2nd quartile is >0.25 and <= 0.5
3rd quartile is >0.5 and <=0.75

But when I try the final line to add those multiple conditions, I get the error:

```
TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
import pandas as pd
path = 'Desktop/customer_features.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path, delimiter=',', header='infer')
#Calculate the percentile for recency, frequency and monetary
df['recencypct'] = df.recency.rank(pct=True)
df['freqencypct'] = df.frequency.rank(pct=True)
df['monencypct'] = df.monetary.rank(pct=True)
#bucket into quartiles 
df.loc[df.recencypct <= 0.25, 'recencyqtl'] = 1
df.loc[df.recencypct > 0.75, 'recencyqtl'] = 4

df.loc[df.recencypct > 0.25 & df.recencypct <=0.5, 'recencyqtl'] = 4
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the `pd.qcut` method? This will categorize your values in quartiles directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a problem with the evaluation order of the functions, as `&` has precedent over `>` and `<=`. Try

```
df.loc[(df.recencypct > 0.25) & (df.recencypct <=0.5), 'recencyqtl'] = 4
```

See the [Python operator precedence table](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html).

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

This task can be easily achieved with the `pd.qcut` method:

```
df['recencyqtl'] = (pd.qcut(df.loc['recency'], 4, labels=['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4']))
```

labels can of course be replaced with anything you want to have, let's say integers as in your question:

```
df['recencyqtl'] = (pd.qcut(df.loc['recency'], 4, labels=[1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

You can also set this as an index to be able to directly access the values in the quartiles:

```
df_quart = df.set_index(pd.qcut(df.loc['recency'], 4, labels=[1, 2, 3, 4]))
# print values of the second quartile Q2:
print(df_quart.loc[(2, ), :])
```

Or cluster the data by the quartiles **and** the index with a multi index:

```
df_quart = df.set_index([pd.qcut(df.loc['recency'], 4, labels=[1, 2, 3, 4]), df.index])
```

Now you can access the quartiles and still have the original index of the data as second level index.